# How to call .exe within WPF application

Tags: c#

How to run one WPF exe (which is in 3.5 framework) from another WPF application (4.0 application).

Reason of the above is:
I'm using some third party which only support 3.5 framework and my existing application is on 4.0. I can't change my current application target type b'coz it has around 200 projects that I need to change then.

I'm stuck with this problem, also I need to pass string as an argument in that.

Below was code that I tried, but didn't get any luck with that:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, param);
 Process.Start(processInfo);
```

EDIT: 
I changed the path and it works for me. But now the problem is I'm not able to get the Command-line argument in the .exe application. Like Currently I'm passing the "param" (it is a string type of array) as an argument to my .exe. But can anyone please help me that how to get this parameter in the .exe file. Means in the window.Loaded handler I want to get this parameter and based on that I want to perform some action.

Comment: Double check the path, does it include the directory and the file.  You might have to pass a startup directory path too, to the overload that accepts more options.

Comment: Retagged question - not WPF or XAML related.

Comment: do you use log to see that app ver 4 get these params or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path you provided is a relative path then check the working directory (Environment.CurrentDirectory) this API as well as many other API will use this as a base path to a create an absolute path when a relative path is provided.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.. I changed the path and it works for me.. But now the problem is I'm not able to get the Command-line argument in the .exe application.

Comment: Like Currently I'm passing the "param" as an argument to my .exe. But ca you please help me that how to get this parameter in the .exe file. Means in the window.Loaded handler I get this parameter and based on that I can trigger some query or any action.

Comment: The command line parameters should be in the string array your main function (in the process you are starting). Also you can see what you get in the command line by accessing Environment.CommandLine

Comment: if you need any more help, you can find me in the C# chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: Sorry but I can't use C# Chat room, as today I created my account in Stackoverflow and I must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk there...

Answer (score 0):

Starting another process will load the required .NET CLR version for that application. There is no problem starting a .NET application that requires a version different than the current one.

Check if the path has a correct value.

Please post any exceptions you are getting.

Comment: Hi Emo, thanks for your answer you are correct, actually the problem was the invalid path, but now stuck with the command-line argument stuff.

Comment: Be aware that you might need to escape or add quotes!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call a .Net 3.5 application from .Net 4.0 application without using `Process.Start()`. Just add the 3.5 exe to your references and now you can use types from that assembly.