# How do I pass command line from a WPF application to another application?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Currently I'm running one WPF exe (which is in 3.5 framework) from another WPF application (4.0 application) by using below code:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("WPFAPP1.exe", "param");
Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Reason of the above is:
I'm using some third party which only support 3.5 framework and my existing application is on 4.0. I can't change my current application target type because it has around 200 projects that I would need to change then.

Now the problem is I want to get the command-line parameter (i.e "param" in my case) in the WPFAPP1.exe. For that I used the below piece of code in the WPFAPP1 application (the .exe application that I'm calling from the Master application),

```
 public static String[] mArgs;
  void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
  {
        if (e.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            mArgs = e.Args;
        }
  }
```

And in the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            String[] args = App.mArgs;
            txtTest.Text = args[0];
        }
```

I tried the above code, but didn't get the respective value (that I passed from the Master application "param"). Also I didn't get any exception or error. Any help will really appreciated on this.

Comment: "it is not working" isn't very descriptive. What's happening? Any reason you're using `args[1]` instead of `args[0]`?

Comment: oh sorry it's a typing mistake.. I'm using args[0] at there...

Comment: Why did you copy your previous question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call .exe within WPF application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772186/how-to-call-exe-within-wpf-application)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo. It's a ProcessStartInfo instance that has an Arguments property that contains all the arguments of the current process.

You could create a new ProcessStartInfo instance and pass the arguments along to any sub-processes.